# Adding names to a text file and searching the names from user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to add names to a text file using file writer and search for the names using scanner class. my problem is when i add more than one name to the text file and search for the names first name added to the text file shows but all the other names does not show.
Here is the code

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
menu();
}

public static void menu() throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("1. Add name");
        System.out.println("2. Done");

        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                addName();
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                verify();
                break;
            }
            default: {
                System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addName() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Names.txt", true);
            writer.write("\r\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
            writer.write(scan.nextLine());

            writer.close();
            System.out.println("name added to file");

            menu();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void verify()
            throws IOException {

        Scanner textfile = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt"));
        Scanner VerifyScnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String Name = VerifyScnr.next();

        while (textfile.hasNext()) {
            
            String search = textfile.next();
            if (search.equalsIgnoreCase(Name)) {
                
                System.out.println("This name is in the file");
                menu();
            } else {
                System.out.println("This name is not in the file");
                verify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated : always follow java naming conventions. All your variable names should go camelCase.

Comment: Just remove `verify();` from the `else` condition.

Comment: If you call `verify()`, it will always restart the process from the beginning, never getting any other element than the first one.

Comment: You should also move the `System.out.println("This name is not in the file");`  to outside of the `while` statement, as you only know if the name is not in the file if you can't find it after reading all the values of the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        menu();
    }

    public static void menu() throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("1. Add name");
        System.out.println("2. Search");
        System.out.println("3. Done");

        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1: {
            addName();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            verify();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            // terminating execution
            System.exit(0);
        }
        default: {
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    public static void addName() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Names.txt", true);
            writer.write("\r\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
            writer.write(scan.nextLine());

            writer.close();
            System.out.println("name added to file");

            menu();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void verify() throws IOException {

        Scanner textfile = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt"));
        Scanner VerifyScnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isFound = false;
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String Name = VerifyScnr.next();

        while (textfile.hasNext()) {
            String search = textfile.next();
            if (search.equalsIgnoreCase(Name)) {
                System.out.println(Name + " is in the file");
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isFound) {
            System.out.println(Name + " is not in the file");
        }
        menu();
    }
}
```